# \prime and \land rendering incorrectly

Tags: math-mode, rendering

So I'm currently having issues where my latex is rendering incorrectlyly

```
$G^\prime=(v^\prime, e^\prime),  v^\prime \subset v \land e^\prime \subset e$
```

What it should render:
[image]

What it is rendering:
[image]

I can't seem to figure out what is blocking this from happening correctly. Since this is a massive document, I tried using the template alone and it seems to be working correctly. Any ideas on what could be happening here ?

Comment: For one, I'd start with searching for every `\def` and `\renewcommand` to see if any important command is overridden.

Comment: By the way, normally `'` does the exact same thing as `^\prime`...

Comment: and, you know, without a MWE it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Welcome to TEX.SE! As it stands, the question appears to be difficult to answer as there is not enough information (i.e. packages, custom macros etc.). Could you try and cut down your code until it is small enough that the error still appears and then edit this into your question please?

Comment: all you have shown is that some definitions in a file that you have not mentioned are incorrect. edit the question to show a _complete_ small document that makes the output shown

Comment: @user202729 well not impossible:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As my crystal ball is shiny this evening, answering given no information in the question.

You clearly have the wrong encoding specified for math fonts, which is usually achieved by loading a package that uses a non standard encoding, then switching to a different font set that uses a standard encoding, for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fdsymbol}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}

$G'+ G^\prime \land X$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem. I realized that I had a different font loaded for displaying code listings and that totally messed things up.